# How to extract ranges with specific length from dataframe row in python?

Tags: python, pandas, range

Here is a first 10 columns of my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    '0': [373.60],
    '1': [442.83],
    '2': [259.21],
    '3': [293.05],
    '4': [332.79],
    '5': [360.03],
    '6': [676.55],
    '7': [481.67],
    '8': [486.59],
    '9': [561.65],
    '10': [491.75]})
```

And so on, actually my df contains 100000 columns. Min is a 109.59, and max is a 1703.35.

I want to slice df into specific ranges with length of 3.98, and then define a ragne that contain a maximum amount of values.
I mean, the ranges must be like:

```
# converting df to array
df_array = np.array(df)

# defining ranges like:
range_length=3.98
range_1 = df_array.min() + range_length
range_2 = range_1 + range_lenght
...
range_n = df_array.max() - range_n-1
```

And then I see that some range_150 contains about 1200 values, which is a most frequent distribution range that I need.

And thet I need to define index of each value from that range in my df..

Really haven't any ideas how to do that. Looks like need create several functions. Can somebody help please?

Comment: can you give an expected output of your example

Comment: How many rows do you have? Or it's just one?

Comment: you have 100 thousand columns or rows..?

Comment: I have a 1 rows × 100000 columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this you get the number of entries for each range:

```
ranges = np.arange(df.T.min()[0] - 5, df.T.max()[0] + 5, 3.98) #added +5 to max and -5 to min to surely include them in the range
df_count = df.T.groupby(pd.cut(df.T[0], ranges)).count()
df_count

                  0
0                  
(254.21, 258.19]  0
(258.19, 262.17]  1
(262.17, 266.15]  0
(266.15, 270.13]  0
(270.13, 274.11]  0
              ..
(660.17, 664.15]  0
(664.15, 668.13]  0
(668.13, 672.11]  0
(672.11, 676.09]  0
(676.09, 680.07]  1
[107 rows x 1 columns]
```

Like this you can get the index (the range) with most hits:

```
df_count.idxmax()

0    (258.19, 262.17]
dtype: object
```

You can get the entries which are in this range like this:

```
df.T[df.T[0].between(258.19, 262.17)]

        0
2  259.21
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: Trying to edit code for my df, you addet +5 and -5 because there is 10 columns, but if my df contains 100 000 columns then I need +50 000 and -50 000?
Anyway, it gives me error "KeyError: 0"

Comment: no. i simply added that because otherwise the values would be outside of this range. you can keep it like this or probably just add 0.01 or similar

Comment: if it gives `KeyError: 0` then your sample df is not as your real data. i cant do anything about that. check the column name of `df.T` and replace the `0` with that name

Comment: But I store my data into `df`, so code must work correctly, but it's doesn't, I remind that my df is 1 row x 100000 columns, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: No, i used your input as it is. Did you check `df.T.columns`?

Comment: Now I understand, I replace the `0` and it works, thanks! But `df_count.idxmax()` gives me output 364    (190.357, 192.911]
dtype: object

Comment: @ker_laeda86 then most of your values are in that range

Comment: Can I ask you again? The `df.T[df.T[0].between(258.19, 262.17)]` extract about 1860 rows, which represents a 1860 columns from original dataframe (that is 365 rows x 100000 columns). How I can extract now this columns from original dataframe? I mean, if that was only several columns, then they can be easy extracted,but if they are 1860..

Comment: `my_cols = df.T[df.T[0].between(258.19, 262.17)].index` should return a list of indexs and you might can access the values by `df[my_cols]` not sure about the types right now. but like this it should be possible. I tested it for the sample input and it works. as result you only get the columns of your original df that represent the values in that range

Comment: Unbelievable, it really works! You made my day mate! If I can ask one more time, can I get not only one range with most hits, but also 10 most-hits ranges?

Comment: you can sort the value by count and get 10 most-hits by `df.head(10)`