# How to access a value from string-like column?

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

I have a pandas dataframe named `intervals`

```
                 num
40  (321.469, 326.854]
41  (326.854, 332.238]
...
68  (472.232, 477.616]
69  (477.616, 483.001]
```

I want to type code that will extract a values `321.469` and `483.001` and store them into variables.

It`s looks like interval type but it isn't, because it's uploaded from excel.

The initial df with real intervals was:

```
In [1]: df_count
Out[1]:     
                       364
                  364   
    (111.479, 116.863]  1
    (116.863, 122.247]  0
    (122.247, 127.632]  1
    (127.632, 133.016]  3
    (133.016, 138.4]    0
    ... ...
    (1436.036, 1441.42] 1
    (1441.42, 1446.805] 0
    (1446.805, 1452.189]1
    (1452.189, 1457.573]0
    (1457.573, 1462.958]1
    251 rows × 1 columns
```

This df was got from my past [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825370/how-to-extract-ranges-with-specific-length-from-dataframe-row-in-python) And I absolutely have no idea how to get about 30 intervals with most count of observations. I don't know why the columns the same name, and when I'm trying to rename `364`, only upper 364 is renamed, but no the intervals column name so I can't access them. So I'm doing this like:

```
df_count.to_excel('ranges.xlsx')
colnames=['num', 'ranges', 'itr'] 
new_df = pd.read_excel(r'ranges.xlsx', names=colnames, header=None)
new_df_sort = new_df.sort_values(by=['ranges'])
top_intervals = new_df_sort.tail(30)
new_intervals = top_intervals.sort_values(by=['num'])
intervals = pd.DataFrame(new_intervals['num'])
```

And, as result, get my `intervals` dataframe mentioned earler. So, maybe there is another way to extract about 30 ranges and then acces a min and max from this intervals.

Can anyone help?

- I'm working with Monte-Carlo simulation to predict a future stock
  price, so thats why I need this intervals. Will be glad to share the result if you interested in.

Thanks!

Comment: the lower 364 is index. Consider changing the name of the present column 364. you have to consider doing this. ```df_count.reset_index(drop = True)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intervals['num'] = intervals['num'].astype('str')

intervals['first_num'] = None
intervals['second_num'] = None

for i in range(len(intevals)):
    intervals.loc[i, 'first_num'] = ''.join(list(intervals.loc[i, 'num'].split(',')[0])[1:])
    intervals.loc[i, 'second_num'] = ''.join(list(intervals.loc[i, 'num'].split(',')[1])[:-1])
```

Comment: may be you dont have a 0 in your index. do ```df.reset_index(drop = True)```

Comment: No still doesn't work. 
`num first_num second_num
0 (306.985, 312.904] None None
1 (312.904, 318.824] None None`
Output of `.reset_index(drop = True)` seems like create a 0 index but next cell still doesn't work.

Comment: tell me how your index looks like?

Comment: I'm use `intervals.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` intstead of `intervals.reset_index(drop = True)`, so now I can access row by index, but now there is another error in last cell: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: try the answer now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206431/discussion-between-bharath-raja-and-ker-laeda86).